# how would I go about moving a piece in my pygame game using the x and y coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, image, animation, pygame, mouse

I need help moving piece to a specific coordinate.
Here is the part of my code that moves a piece:

```
    screen.blit(mountain, (300, 500))
    screen.blit(mountain, (300, 400))
def enemy_castle():
    castle = pygame.image.load('castle.png')
    castle = pygame.transform.scale(castle, (100, 100))
    screen.blit(castle, (0, 500))
def player_castle():
    castle = pygame.image.load('castle.png')
    castle = pygame.transform.scale(castle, (100, 100))
    screen.blit(castle, (500, 0))
def enemy_sorcerer():
    s_piece = pygame.image.load('sorcerer.png')
    s_piece = pygame.transform.scale(s_piece, (100, 100))
    screen.blit(s_piece, (400, 0))
    screen.blit(s_piece, (500, 100))
```

Comment: making a chess like game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an image, that needs to be draw to a specific location.  So instead of "hard coding" that `(500, 0)`, start storing that in a variable.

The PyGame Rect class would be perfect for this, since it can also be used with the `blit()` function, and already has a bunch of [handy collision functions](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).

You can create a Rect, simply by asking the image for its Rect - except this is positioned at `(0,0)`, because an image has no concept of a location.

```
castle_image = pygame.image.load('castle.png').convert_alpha()
castle_image = pygame.transform.scale(castle_image, (100, 100))
castle_rect  = castle_image.get_rect()
castle_rect.topleft = ( 500, 0 )
screen.blit( castle_image, castle_rect )
```

So now the variable `castle_rect` would be something like `[ x=500, y=0, width=100, height=100 ]`

To move the drawing position of the image, now all you need to do is adjust the co-ordinates of `castle_rect`, for example:

```
castle_rect.x += 10
castle_rect.y += 100
screen.blit( castle_image, castle_rect )
```

Or, just move the whole image by resetting its co-ordinates again:

```
castle_rect.topleft = ( 200, 200 )
screen.blit( castle_image, castle_rect )
```

What would be more efficient, is to load & scale your images *once* on start-up, but then paint them all inside a main-loop at their current rectangle-positions.

```
def loadImageWithScale( image_filename, size=(100,100) ):
    """ Load the given image file, then rescale the image to size """
    new_image = pygame.image.load( image_filename ).convert_alpha()
    new_image = pygame.transform.scale( new_image, size )
    return new_image

def getImageRectAt( image, position ):
    return image.get_rect( topleft=position )

# Load images
enemy_castle   = loadImageWithScale( 'castle.png' )
enemy_sorcerer = loadImageWithScale( 'sorcerer.png' )
player_castle  = loadImageWithScale( 'castle.png' )

# Set initial positions
enemy_castle_rect   = getImageRectAt( enemy_castle,   ( 0, 500 ) )
enemy_sorceror_rect = getImageRectAt( enemy_sorceror, ( 400, 0 ) )
player_castle_rect  = getImageRectAt( player_castle,  ( 500, 0 ) )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
exiting = False
while not exiting:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            exiting = True

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( ( 128, 128, 128 ) )
    window.blit( enemy_castle,   enemy_castle_rect )
    window.blit( enemy_sorceror, enemy_sorceror_rect )
    window.blit( player_castle,  player_castle_rect )

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )

pygame.quit()
```

Probably when you get a lot more screen elements, you could arrange them into convenient lists to make the drawing code more concise.